# d3.js functions not working with div id

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am writing one chart function using d3. But it is not working.
Please help any one.

```
    <script>

    var chart=function(a){
        var w=960,h=500;
        var svg=d3.select('#a')
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",w).attr("height",h);

        svg
            .append("text")
            .text("hello world").attr("x",100).attr("y",100);
    }
    chart(context);

    </script>
```

the div tag id is 'context' ().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are passing `"#a"` as a string. You have to concatenate the string `"#"` with your argument.

For instance, look at this snippet:

```js
var foo = "bar";

console.log("#foo");
console.log("#" + foo);
```

The first console.log gives you `"#foo"`, because it's just a string. The second one gives you the value of `foo`.

So, your code should be:

```
<script>

var chart=function(a){
    var w=960,h=500;
    var svg=d3.select('#' + a)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width",w).attr("height",h);

    svg
        .append("text")
        .text("hello world").attr("x",100).attr("y",100);
}
chart(context);

</script>
```